# Отсутствуют права на запись

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Использую `laravel+nginx`. Допустим утром сделал `chown -R 777 www-data /var/www/site`. Пару суток работает, потом появляются ошибки

```
2019/09/14 18:19:23 [error] 545#545: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/site/storage/logs/laravel-2019-09-14.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/site/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
```

Снова даю права на запись. Перезапускаю nginx. Снова работает пару дней. Подскажите в чем траблы

Comment: У вас, судя по названию, файл laravel-2019-09-14.log создаётся каждый день. Проверьте права именно этого файла. Веб-сервер должен иметь права на запись в этот файл. Скорее всего, веб-сервер не является владельцем этого файла.

Comment: @Undefined, ларавел запускается под рутом, nginx работает под www-data

Comment: Надо вначале разобраться с этим:
1. Права файла (laravel-2019-09-14.log), к какому владельцу и группе он принадлежит.
2. Какой пользователь пытается открыть этот файл.

Comment: @Radzhab Если бы у вас ларавел работал под рутом, он бы мог читать и писать в любом файле, независимого от chmod.

Comment: Проверьте, как вам посоветовал @Undefined, под каким пользователем работает php-fpm (NGINX). У меня к примеру он работает под ubuntu, и я добавил этого пользователя в группу www-data. После этого, ставя chown www-data:www-data проблема была решена и этот пользователь, будучи в группе имел права на запись.

Answer (score 0):

Ни в коем случае не давайте права 777 на директорию. Попробуйте прописать на  папку storage

sudo chgrp -R www-data storage
sudo chmod -R g+wx storage